# How to search for more than 1 word using a Web Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services

In my app, you can search for a "book", and the web service will return json data of cheap books and all their properties, but if you searched for a specific book like "Harry Potter", it would crash. My app can only handle one word searches, and I would like to know how to do multiple word searches. My URL looks like this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://us.api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/products?query=%@&app_id=APP_ID&app_key=APP_KEY", searchedItem.text];
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: The crash comes from the app or the webservice?

Comment: the app, not the web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://us.api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/products?query=%@&app_id=APP_ID&app_key=APP_KEY", 
     [[searchedItem.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"
    ]
   ];
```